# As we can pass integer from razor page to controller by asp-route-id , how can we pass a string instead?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

With the help of anchor tag

```
<a asp-controller="controller-name" asp-action="method-name" asp-route-id="1"> hyperlink </a>
```

it provokes the following in C#

```
controller-name/method-name/1
```

but how can I achieve the following?

```
controller-name/method-name/string
```

Comment: You need to use string variable as a parameter to the api endpoint

Comment: i would appreciate if u please elaborate how to pass string as a parameter ? @PrasadTelkikar

Comment: @AsadMirza just put a string variable in it `asp-route-id="string"`. In fact, parameters in url are all string.

Comment: @mj1313 yes u r right , thanks , sorry for late reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstlt,the default data format of string in url is `controller-name/method-name/1` If you want to get string in action,you only need to use `string Id` rather than `int Id`.Here is a demo:

View:

```
<a asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Method" asp-route-id="1" asp-route-name="name1"> hyperlink </a>
```

url:

```
https://localhost:xxxx/Test/Method/1?name=name1
```

Controller：

```
public IActionResult Method(string Id, string Name) {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: thanks dear for your brief reply , sorry could nt reply earlier ...